# FlatMap in scala

Tags: scala

I want to write my own class `ErrorOr`, in which there will be cases `Some` and `Failure`. I need to write my own `flatMap()`, but an error pops up on the second line. How do I fix it?

```
object adt:
  
  enum ErrorOr[+V]:

    /* 
      Two case: 
       a case for a regular value
       a case for an error (it should contain an actual throwable)
     */
    
    case Some(x: V) extends ErrorOr[V]

    case Failure extends ErrorOr[Throwable]
    
    /* 
      in case of failing the method with exception
      no exception is thrown but the case for an error is returned
    */ 

    def flatMap[Q](f: V ⇒ ErrorOr[Q]): ErrorOr[Q] =
      this match
        case ErrorOr.Some(v)  ⇒ f(v)
        case ErrorOr.Failure  ⇒ ErrorOr[Q].Failure
```

Comment: "an error pops up on the second line. How do I fix it?“ – I guess a good start would be to read the error message and figure out why it appears, then after you have figured it out, change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your enum.
I think you are trying to do something similar to the `Try[T]`.
You can look at the top declaration of the [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) and its child classes [Success](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Success.html) [Failure](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Failure.html).

In the idea of Try.Failure, you can rewrite your ErrorOr.Failure as :

```
    case Failure(e : Throwable) extends ErrorOr[V]
```

Do not forget to change your `flatMap(f)` as Failure takes an argument

Comment: thank you, I fixed flatMap(f) and it worked!